# Replace disk with a smaller one without reinstalling Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, dd, clone, cloning

I have 1TB disk with Ubuntu and I want to replace it with 500GB without uninstalling the system. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be possible.

First, plug in your new hard drive e. g. using a hard drive enclosure and boot from a live CD. Shrink root partition so it fits the new hard drive. Then, create images of boot and root partition. If you're on UEFI, backup the EFI partition too. You can create images either using GNOME Disks or the dd command.

I recommend creating partitions of the same sizes as on old hard drive first. You can then just copy one partition and flash it to another using dd.

Power off your computer, if you're on a laptop, remove the battery or put it in battery safe mode.

Replace your hard drive with the new one and power on your computer.

**NOTE:** If you're using legacy boot, there's one more step. Your computer will probably fail to boot because you haven't copied the MBR too. You can fix this by using **boot-repair** in the live CD.

Comment: If gpt(GUID), you cannot image copy partitions as GUID is in primary partition table, backup partition table & each partition. They cannot get out of sync without major issue. If also keeping old drive, you cannot have duplicate UUIDs (or GUIDs), so image copy not always easiest way. You can do a new install & restore from your backups, just like you would when a hard drive totally fails.Becomes good test that backup is complete as you still have old drive for anything you forgot. You can use cp -a or rsync, but have to make changes to system to use newer UUIDs. New install & restore easier.